# How to SELECT COUNT DISTINCT?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, distinct-values

I have problem to select COUNT distinct: The answer I need is 6.
The Time different is < 300Sec in count as 1.
My sql :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(cast([Date] as date) + cast([time] as datetime)))
FROM [Table1]WHERE [DATE] = '2013-06-22'
AND ErrCode = 'Scrubber Failure'AND Frequency = 1
```

[image]

Comment: What database system you're using?

Comment: Looks like SQL server with [Date] syntax

Comment: Alex - SQL Server 2008

Comment: What if the results of your condition will overlap?

Comment: overlap? as long as the time diff is below than 300s AND equipment in same Group= 'A'. Count it as 1 only.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT 
             ROUND(CONVERT(DECIMAL(20, 4), 
                     DATEDIFF(minute, 
                              CONVERT(datetime, '2013-01-01 00:00:00', 120), 
                              CONVERT(datetime, date + ' ' + time, 120))) / 5, 0)) n
  FROM table1
 WHERE date = '2013-06-22'
   AND errcode = 'Scrubber Failure'
   AND frequency = 1
```

Output:

```
| N |
-----
| 6 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b74cb/29)** demo.

Comment: tq for replying... hmm u are comparing with '2013-01-01 00:00:00'(fixed date). Hmm.. I thinking, what will happen if there is data for '2014-06-22'(already update the schema). Why is it u devide by (/5) ? With new schema the answer should be = 7.

Comment: Well any date <= lower end of of your date filter in WHERE clause can be used as a base date and only needed to calc time difference in minutes. In your particular example it as well can be '2013-06-22'. 300 sec / 60 = 5 minutes interval, and that's why the diff is divided by 5. Now here is updated sqlfiddle with date `2014-06-22` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1ebf0/1. The result is 7.

Comment: hmm.. i already update the schema. Now the answer sholud be 7. Because the DATEDIFF(SECOND,'2014-06-22 08:19:26','2014-06-22 08:20:26') is < 300 seconds. Pls advice.

Comment: @user2286756 Did you see my updated sqlfiddle? Where did you update the schema??? If you changed my sqlfiddle then you should click `build schema` grab a new link in you browser and post it here.

Comment: See updated answer and here is updated sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b74cb/29 which gives you your answer.

Comment: I already update the schema.. And my sql, it is almost there BUT I not able to get datediff for the last row... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/da2b4/1